# GNU sed : print new line after pattern space using the s command

Tags: bash, sed

*BSD sed: always appends a newline on output, even if the input line doesn't end in one.*

*GNU sed: preserves the trailing-newline status, i.e., it appends a newline only if the input line ended in one.*

**Is there a way to emulate the behavior of BSD sed in GNU sed?**

Example:

Output of nvidia-smi:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.66       Driver Version: 450.66       CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 108...  Off  | 00000000:26:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
|  0%   49C    P8     9W / 250W |     18MiB / 11177MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce GTX 1050    Off  | 00000000:27:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 57%   44C    P8    N/A /  75W |      7MiB /  2000MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

My sed command:

```
 loads=$(eval nvidia-smi | sed -nr 's/.*\s([0-9]+)MiB\s*\/\s*([0-9]+)MiB.*/\1 \2/p')
```

Output in BSD sed:

```
# echo $loads
# 18 11177
# 7 2000
```

Output in GNU sed:

```
# echo $loads
# 18 11177 7 2000
```

I have tried everything that I came across, including exchanging hold and pattern spaces, but just cant get GNU sed to print a new line after the first pattern.

Comment: Could you post details about your shell / OS ? I can't reproduce your issue with GNU sed v 4.7

Comment: `eval nvidia-smi` ? Just `nvidia-smi`... It's like doing `eval eval eval eval echo`. Just run the command.

Comment: Maybe all you need is `nvidia-smi --query-gpu=memory.used,memory.total --format=csv,nounits,noheader`? Or, `loads=$(nvidia-smi --query-gpu=memory.used,memory.total --format=csv,nounits,noheader)` and then `echo "${loads//,/ }" if you need a space between the two values`?

Comment: Also, try `echo "$loads"`, newlines are removed from unquoted variables in expansion

Comment: @gforce89: That's not the echo, it's the shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are using zsh on the BSD (macOS?). It's the difference between bash and zsh.

```
[zsh] $ v=$( printf '%s\n' hello world )
[zsh] $ echo $v
hello
world
[zsh] $

[bash] $ v=$( printf '%s\n' hello world )
[bash] $ echo $v
hello world
[bash] $ echo "$v"
hello
world
[bash] $
```